# What is the most efficient way to handle 3 star characters that I don't want?

Tags: naruto-blazing

I have an abundance of 3 star characters that I don't want or need. What's the most efficient way of handling them all? Should I sell them or use them to train my 5 or 4 star characters?

Note: These are also characters that I will never use to level up luck and abilities in other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excess 3-star characters can of course be used for quick XP or extra cash in a pinch but as stated in the earlier answer it can be much more prudent to hang onto them if you have the room in the event that you obtain a higher rated version of the same character and want to get some skills.

Though if as you say you have no intention whatsoever to acquire skills for these characters there is very little reason to hang onto them unless you need to fill an empty slot when going for special conditions in emergency missions like having characters of a particular type or below a certain character cost.

Answer (score -1):

I just dupe them for abilities

Comment: From review: As bad as this answer is, it's still tries to answer this question. The community will vote this down hardly, but it is an answer.